# Firebase auth with Microsoft gives null user object

Tags: javascript, azure, firebase-authentication

I am implementing user sign-in for web with Google Firebase. I have this working for Google and Facebook (I am getting a populated `user` object), but for Microsoft sign in I am getting `null` in the `user` object even after authorizing at the login screen.

My code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";
import {
    getAuth,
    signInWithRedirect,
    getRedirectResult,
    signOut,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    FacebookAuthProvider,
    OAuthProvider, // microsoft
    onAuthStateChanged
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = { /* my settings */ };
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebase);

document.querySelector('.login-with button.microsoft').addEventListener('click', microsoftSignIn, false);

function microsoftSignIn() {
    const provider = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
}

onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("user is logged in", user);
    } else {
        console.log("user is not logged in");
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
});
```

In Azure AD I have set the redirect URI to https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler. I also threw in the localhost though I suspect it is not necessary:

[image: azure ad authentication screen]

I gave it permission to log users in:

[image: azure api permissions]

And I have copied over the client ID and secret back to firebase auth.

When I test the login I get this:

[image: microsoft my-app auth screen]

Then after I accept I am redirected back to my site but the `user` object is `null`. How can I get a populated `user` object? Also note that even when using ngrok to host my site on a https URL the result is the same.

Comment: Are you using Safari? Can you try with different browser and use signInWithPopup replacing signInWithRedirect.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'profile' scope to the OAuthProvider? - - provider.addScope('profile')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through this just in January.

You will have to verify yourself as a publisher.

As stated in image 2:

> Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant
> consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified
> publishers.

This means if your Microsoft AD "App" is available for multi tenants, you will need to complete the registration.

You can only be unverified if you are building a single tenant app.

Also please note, if you are using a Microsoft Account that is part of a Active Directory, like a school or work account, the admin of the AD has to register fist and give consent for the app to connect to the AD, before other users can consent.

So if you are testing the login flow in your app, it is best to do it with a personal microsoft account or with an account that is part of an Active Directory where you have admin rights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I click "Learn more" on the page you mention it takes me here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview where it says "The app that's to be publisher verified must be registered by using an Azure AD work or school account. Apps that are registered by using a Microsoft account can't be publisher verified." Are you sure you were able to get it working using only a Personal Microsoft account?

Comment: Hi, we did not use a personal microsoft account to create the app. We used a organization account. All of this is due to microsofts compliance policy. If you are using a personal account - to my best knowledge - you can not create a multi tenant app.
By testing it I mean when you are trying to log in with an account via your app and firebase, use a personal account and not an account that is part of a AD.
I will edit the answer to make it more clear.